# SwiftUI: @State value doesn't update after async network request

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, binding, state

My aim is the change data in `DetailView()`. Normally in this case I'm using `@State` + `@Binding` and it's works fine with static data, but when I trying to update ViewModel with data from network request I'm loosing functionality of `@State` (new data doesn't passing to `@State` value it's stays empty). I checked network request and decoding process - everything ok with it. Sorry my code example a bit long but it's the shortest way that I found to recreate the problem...

**Models:**

```
    struct LeagueResponse: Decodable {
        var status: Bool?
        var data: [League] = []
    }
    
    struct League: Codable, Identifiable {
        let id: String
        let name: String
        var seasons: [Season]?
        
    }
    
    struct SeasonResponse: Codable {
        var status: Bool?
        var data: LeagueData?
    }
    
    struct LeagueData: Codable {
        let name: String?
        let desc: String
        let abbreviation: String?
        let seasons: [Season]
    }
    
    struct Season: Codable {
        let year: Int
        let displayName: String
        
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class LeagueViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var leagues: [League] = []
    
    init() {
        Task {
            try await getLeagueData()
        }
    }
    
    private func getLeagueData() async throws {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://api-football-standings.azharimm.site/leagues")!)
        guard let leagues = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LeagueResponse.self, from: data) else {
            throw URLError(.cannotParseResponse)
        }
        await MainActor.run {
            self.leagues = leagues.data
        }
    }
    
    func loadSeasons(forLeague id: String) async throws {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://api-football-standings.azharimm.site/leagues/\(id)/seasons")!)
        guard let seasons = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SeasonResponse.self, from: data) else {
            throw URLError(.cannotParseResponse)
        }
        await MainActor.run {
            if let responsedLeagueIndex = leagues.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }),
               let unwrappedSeasons = seasons.data?.seasons {
                leagues[responsedLeagueIndex].seasons = unwrappedSeasons
                print(unwrappedSeasons) // successfully getting and parsing data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Views:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = LeagueViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if vm.leagues.isEmpty {
                    ProgressView()
                } else {
                    List {
                        ForEach(vm.leagues) { league in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(league: league)) {
                                Text(league.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Leagues"), displayMode: .large)
        }
        .environmentObject(vm)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: LeagueViewModel
    @State var league: League
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let unwrappedSeasons = league.seasons {
                List {
                    ForEach(unwrappedSeasons, id: \.year) { season in
                        Text(season.displayName)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                try await vm.loadSeasons(forLeague: league.id)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("League Detail"), displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                ChangeButton(selectedLeague: $league)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChangeButton: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: LeagueViewModel
    @Binding var selectedLeague: League // if remove @State the data will pass fine
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(vm.leagues) { league in
                Button {
                    self.selectedLeague = league
                } label: {
                    Text(league.name)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "calendar")
        }
    }
}
```

**Main goals:**

1. Show selected league seasons data in `DetailView()`
2. Possibility to change seasons data in `DetailView()` when another league was chosen in `ChangeButton()`

Comment: I would make vm an @ObservedObject in the detail  view and pass it from the parent view

Comment: @JoakimDanielson changed `@EnvironmentObject` to `@ObservedObject` and passed `@StateObject` to views - same result, nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You update view model but DetailView contains *a copy* of league (because it is value type).

The simplest seems to me is to return in callback seasons, so there is possibility to update local league as well.

[image: demo]

```
func loadSeasons(forLeague id: String, completion: (([Season]) -> Void)?) async throws {

     // ...

    await MainActor.run {
        if let responsedLeagueIndex = leagues.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }),
           let unwrappedSeasons = seasons.data?.seasons {
            leagues[responsedLeagueIndex].seasons = unwrappedSeasons

            completion?(unwrappedSeasons) // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

and make task dependent on league id so selection would work, like:

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: LeagueViewModel
    @State var league: League

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ... 
        }
        .task(id: league.id) {    // << here !!
            Task {
                try await vm.loadSeasons(forLeague: league.id) {
                    league.seasons = $0  // << update local copy !!
                }
            }
        }
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestAsyncUpdateSelectionMatching.swift)

Comment: Slight improvement would be to capture not only the `[Season]`, but the entire `League`. At the moment `league.name` is unchanged despite other data will change.

Answer (score 1):

One question is if you already made `LeagueViewModel` an `ObservableObject`, why don't you display from it directly, and simply pass an `id` to your `DetailView`?

So your detail view will be:

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: LeagueViewModel
    @State var id: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let unwrappedSeasons = vm.leagues.first { $0.id == id }?.seasons {
                List {
                    ForEach(unwrappedSeasons, id: \.year) { season in
                        Text(season.displayName)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .task(id: id) {
            Task {
                try await vm.loadSeasons(forLeague: id)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("League Detail"), displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                ChangeButton(selectedId: $id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view will automatically update season data as it loads them.